# Dynamic textbox generation with buttons to generate a child subset of textboxes

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm working in MVC and was trying to use jquery to perform the following, if there is an easier way i'd be happy to hear it...

I'm looking to have my form create dynamic input to produce something for example that could look like this: *i won't know how many subcat's they are going to enter nor how many main categories.

```
category0 <btnInsertSubCat0>
subcat0.0
subcat0.1
subcat0.2

category1 <btnInsertSubCat1>
subcat1.0 
subcat1.1 

<btbInsertNewCat>
```

I can produce a button that appends textboxes one after another as well as a button next to it but even if I use the .live attribute I can't get the subcat button to fire.  Changed code around a lot and looked at different tutorial to no avail, fig. this would be semi easy to do?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                var procID = 0;
                var orgID = 0;

                $('.clickme').live('click', function () {
                    var newItem = $("<input type='text' name='Procedure[" + procID + "]' value='Procedure[" + procID + "] />");
                    var newLabel = $("<br /><label id='Label[" + procID + "]' >ProcedureID: [" + procID + "]</label>");
                    var newDiv = $("<div class='objective'><b>Insert Objective</b>[" + procID + "." + orgID + "]</div>");
                    $("#procedureHolder").append(newLabel);
                    $("#procedureHolder").append(newItem);
                    $("#procedureHolder").append(newDiv);
                    procID++;
                });

                $('.objective').live('click', function () {
                    var newObj = $("<input type='text' id='Objective[" + (procID - 1) + "." + orgID + "]' >ObjectiveID: [" + (procID - 1) + "." + orgID + "]</label>");
                    $("#procedureHolder").append(newObj);
                    orgID++;
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited my post, 
figured it out on my own how to utilize *jquery* to create an unlimited number of *child dynamic textboxes*. They all post back in the form collection as well.  I figured out why the objectives weren't showing up, turns out i was declaring `ID rather than Name`.  
Thanks!

Comment: cool, glad you got it to work. Yeah ID instead of name is an easy one to stuff-up.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following approach for a dynamic search screen using ASP.NET MVC. Search options where managed in a database mapped to a product. This allowed the marketing team to tweak searching results and the search options in the admin section of the website. Essentially the approach was the following:

```
    public class FormFieldCollection : List<FormField>
    {
        public string FormFieldType { get; set; }
    }

    public class FormField
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string Type {get;set;}
        public string Value {get;set;}
        public bool IsChecked {get;set;}
    }

    public class FormFieldModel
    {
        public FormFieldCollection PaymentOptions { get; set; }
    }
```

In the view generated from either custom Helper or use a foreach. 
In your Controller action something like:

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(FormCollection formCollection) 
{
   //search through the results, map back to class or loop through key value pairs.
}
```

View Code, obviously include some nice html markup to format  the form.

```
@Model FormFieldCollection 
@{     
      View.Title = "Form";     
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_defaultMaster.cshtml"; 
 }
   @foreach(var formField in Model){
      <input type="@formField.Type" id="@formField.Name" name="@formField.Name"   value=""@formField.Value"" />   
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeActionMethodAdd", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post)) 
{

   //Submit form to 
   Field Name: <input type="text" value="" />  * must be unique

   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

}

Syntax mightn't be perfect just going of memory for razor.

Comment: What would the jquery look like to utilize this approach? So that an end user can click a button to insert a textbox, placeholder, and inner button.  if that first button was clicked again it would generate the same objects with unique id's, if the inner button was clicked another textbox would be generated and attached to the associated placeholder.  Is that more clear?  I'm struggling with the jquery code.

Comment: I updated my jquery code, within the formcollection I'm not seeing my dynamic objectives, all the procedures display correctly.  I'll try implementing something similar to the formviewmodel approach you provided to see if I can get all the values to pass through the formcollection.